# Case When mutiple results

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need to implement Case When statement in My View With multiple Result

As Shown Below in My View

[image]

i write it as Below but it give me problem ( i Need to make range of Value with  - Between Value And Value then Result -  )

```
    Case [Total] when 
between 15000 and 50000 then  '2%'
when between 50001 and 75000 then '3%'
when between 75001 and 10000 then '4%' 
Else '0'
End As [Case]
```

But the Above Code Is Not Working

So i Tried this Code But its not Working Also

```
    Case When  [Total] 
between 15000 and 50000 then  '2%'
between 50001 and 75000 then '3%'
between 75001 and 10000 then '4%' 
Else '0'
End As [Case]
```

Answer (score 3):

You must use the long syntax of `CASE` here:

```
CASE WHEN [Total] BETWEEN 15000 AND 50000 THEN '2%'
     WHEN [Total] BETWEEN 50001 AND 75000 THEN '3%'
     WHEN [Total] BETWEEN 75001 AND 10000 THEN '4%'
     ELSE '0' END AS [Case]
```

The other, shortened, syntax of `CASE` you were using is only allowed when comparing a column to specific scalar values, not ranges.  For example, the following would work:

```
CASE [Total] WHEN 15000 THEN '2%'
             WHEN 50001 THEN '3%'
             ...
             ELSE '0' END AS [Case]
```

Comment: *Nitpick:* I wouldn't call it the "long" syntax, just the "other" syntax. `CASE a WHEN b THEN ...` is like a `switch` statement, while `CASE WHEN a = b THEN ...` is like an `if-elseif` statement. One is not just a shorter version of the other, they are two *alternate* syntax's, to accomplish the task in different ways. And the "long" `if-elseif` is *not always* the same as the "short" `switch`, because the `switch` only evaluates `a` once. --- Yes, in code you can assign `a` to a variable and use it in `if-else`, but in SQL that would be much more cumbersome.

Comment: The plural of "syntax" is either "syntaces" or "syntaxes".

Comment: Sorry, that's what I typed. but my web browser spell checker said to use `'`, but you are [right](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65541/plural-of-syntax).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be something like this:

```
case
    when [Total] >  75000
            then '4%'
    when [Total] >  50000
            then '3%'
    when [Total] >= 15000
            then '2%'
            else '0%'
end as [Case]
```